# Получить числа из строки после определенного слова

Tags: javascript, html, css

Из атрибута href данных ссылок мне нужно получить числа 127885836, 223388436 и 852485236. Как это можно сделать? Числа могут быть разные, но они всегда будут идти после слова goods/ и до символа тире.

```
<div class="item">
  <a href="https://www.test.org/goods/127885836-truba_vodostochnaya_d150kh2000" class="link">Link</a>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <a href="https://www.test.org/goods/223388436-truba_vodostochnaya_d350kh1001" class="link">Link</a>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <a href="https://www.test.org/goods/852485236-truba_vodostochnaya_d250kh1002" class="link">Link</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

это просто методами массивов и строк. можно еще регулярками, но я не умею

```js
const links = document.querySelectorAll('a')

const arr = Array.from(links)
.reduce((acc, link) => {
    const href = link.href

    let result = href.split('goods/')
    result = result[1].split('-')
    result = result[0]

    acc.push(result)
    return acc
}, [])

console.log(arr)
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <a href="https://www.test.org/goods/127885836-truba_vodostochnaya_d150kh2000" class="link">Link</a>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <a href="https://www.test.org/goods/223388436-truba_vodostochnaya_d350kh1001" class="link">Link</a>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <a href="https://www.test.org/goods/852485236-truba_vodostochnaya_d250kh1002" class="link">Link</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Отлично, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

> Из атрибута href данных ссылок мне нужно получить числа 127885836, 223388436 и 852485236. Как это можно сделать?

Еще вот так можно...

```js
const arr = []
document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(o => arr.push(o.href.match(/\d+/)[0]))

console.log(arr)
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <a href="https://www.test.org/goods/127885836-truba_vodostochnaya_d150kh2000" class="link">Link</a>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <a href="https://www.test.org/goods/223388436-truba_vodostochnaya_d350kh1001" class="link">Link</a>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <a href="https://www.test.org/goods/852485236-truba_vodostochnaya_d250kh1002" class="link">Link</a>
</div>
```